# React Router's NavLink keep implemented its className's method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, deployment, react-router

I'm using React Router version 6.14, and I have a weird issue. I'm using the `NavLink` in this way:

```
<nav>
    <NavLink className={ ({isActive}) => isActive ? 'active' : null } to='/host'>Host</NavLink>
    <NavLink className={ ({isActive}) => isActive ? 'active' : null } to='/about'>About</NavLink>
    <NavLink className={ ({isActive}) => isActive ? 'active' : null } to='/vans'>Vans</NavLink>
</nav>
```

The CSS of the 'active' is simply:

```
.active {
  color: #161616;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The problem is if I remove the className attribute from the NavLink, its method still being implemented. Even if I restart the program it's still hapening, like it's remember that line of code. Only if I remvoe the 'active' section from the CSS file it stops.

Does anyone know anything about this strange bug?

Comment: Can you clarify what method is still being implemented, what that means exactly? Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue you describe that we could inspect live?

Comment: OK, I made a sample of this problem in codesandbox, how can I share this? @DrewReese

Comment: In the upper-right corner of the sandbox there should be a button to share, in the little dropdown that opens you can copy a link to share here in the post or in a comment. You could probably also just copy/paste the URL from the address bar.

Comment: I think that's the URL: [https://codesandbox.io/embed](https://codesandbox.io/embed/brave-lederberg-2xhsdw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). I hope you'll see what I see. There is no definition for a className anymore but still the color of the active link change. The `Navbar` is being used in the `Header` component. @DrewReese

Comment: The `NavLink` components change because still you have a `.active` CSS rule defined in `index.css`. Is this what you are still seeing used? The `NavLink` component applies an [`"active"` classname by default](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link#default-active-class) for actively matched links.

Comment: Oh wow so that's why it's happening. I didn't know that, I called this class "active" simply out of instinct. Thank you so much !! 

Comment: No worries, glad to help. I've voted to close this question as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Drew Reese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese) the question is answered, I'll share the solution here in case others come across it. It turns out that by default, an `active` class is added to a `NavLink` component when it is active. That's why if there's a class in the CSS file called "active", it will affect the active `NavLink`, even if there's no definition to its className.

The documentation that refer to this: [default-active-class](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link#default-active-class)